# Getting Pod and Node's events millisecond level precision in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, events, client-go

I have a Kubernetes cluster and I need to collect the various pod and node event timestamps.

I do that by building a go service that communicates with my Kubernetes cluster via client-go library. The timestamp I get for the subscribed pod and node object shows time only till seconds precision.

Is there a way one can get time in milliseconds precision level? I found a [similar issue raised](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81026) but there is no resolution of that.

Could someone help me in this?

Comment: Have you already tried the Watch api, which AIUI triggers as they happen (instead of a polling approach and then consulting the Event's timestamp)? I guess the rest of the question is what would your system _do_ by knowing a Pod was scheduled at 1620936556001 versus 1620936556002? Are you trying to build a lambda-billing replacement?

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for your reply. I have written a customer controller that uses informer to get the events for the resource object I have subscribed to ( I am not using watch api ) as they happen (It uses the same concept that currently exists in Kubernetes for existing controller that watch the resource object for addition/deletion or update). The timestamp that I get is in second precision level.

Comment: @mdaniel Also, I am trying to measure the overhead at the milliseconds level, thus the need for such a timestamp. Does the timestamp stored in the etcd datastore is at seconds level precision or any idea where does it get chopped off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the community @shresthi-garg

First of all, as you correctly found, it's not possible to get precise timestamps from kubernetes components themselves with milliseconds precision. And [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81026#issuecomment-832301082) is closed for now.

However it's still possible to find some exact timings about containers and other events. Below is an example related to a container.

**Option 1** - kubelet by default writes significant amount of logs to syslog. It's possible to view them with using `journalctl` (note! this approach works on `systemd` systems. For other systems please refer to [official kubenetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs)). Example of the command:

`journalctl -u kubelet -o short-precise`

-u - filter by unit

-o - output options

Line from output which we're looking for will be:

```
May 18 21:00:30.221950 control-plane kubelet[8576]: I0518 21:00:30.221566    8576 scope.go:111] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d7d0403807684ddd4d2597d32b90b1e27d31f082d22cededde26f6da8281cd92"
```

**Option 2** - get this information from containerisation engine. In the example below I used Docker for this.
I run this command:

`docker inspect container_id/container_name`

Output will be like:

```
{
        "Id": "d7d0403807684ddd4d2597d32b90b1e27d31f082d22cededde26f6da8281cd92",
        "Created": "2021-05-18T21:00:07.388569335Z",
        "Path": "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "nginx",
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 8478,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-05-18T21:00:07.593216613Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it did clarify my doubt. @WytrzymałyWiktor